# sharepoint, workflow, publish globally

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer, publishing, reusable

I'm using SharePoint designer 2010,
I have create reusble workflow and publish it.

when I associate the workflow to a list, do I create a copy of that workflow or this is apointer to the source workflow? if I do some changes in the source workflow I will see those changes at the workflow that I associate to the list?

is it possible if I will globally publish it?